# Sidekiq - job stuck in enqueued

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, delayed-paperclip

I have a rails 4 app.  I'm using paperclip and delayed_paperclip with sidekiq.  The background job is being picked up by sidekiq but it just hangs forever in the Enqueued queue.
This is what I see on sidekiq:

```
{"job_class"=>"DelayedPaperclip::Jobs::ActiveJob", "job_id"=>"946856ca-c90e-4bb4-9f41-1f1e59269acb", "queue_name"=>"paperclip", "arguments"=>["User", 109, "avatar"]}
```

In my User model I have:

```
  process_in_background :avatar
```

procfile.yml

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
```

I have read all related issues to this question and still couldn't figure out the issue.  Thoughts anyone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You've enqueued the job to the `paperclip` queue but you have not configured Sidekiq to pull jobs from that queue:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q default -q paperclip
```

Comment: Still no go.  Changed my profile to this:  `worker: bundle exec sidekiq -q default -q paperclip`